# Cascade delete in phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have 3 models:

```
schema "m1s" do
  (...)
  has_many :m2s, MyApp.M2, on_delete: :delete_all
end

schema "m2s" do
  (...)
  belongs_to :m1s, MyApp.M1
  many_to_many :m3s, MyApp.M3, join_through: MyApp.M3sM2, on_delete: :delete_all
end

schema "m3s" do
  (...)
  many_to_many :m2s, MyApp.M2, join_through: MyApp.M2sM3
end

schema "m2s_m3s" do
  (...)
  belongs_to :m2, MyApp.M2
  belongs_to :m3, MyApp.M3
end
```

Deleting from M1 triggers deletion from M2.

Deleting from M2 triggers deletion from M2sM3.

So I'd assume that deleting from M1 triggers deletion from M2sM3.

But when I try to delete M1, if there are elements in the m2s_m3 table, I get this error:

```
** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 23503 (foreign_key_violation): update or delete on table "m2s" violates foreign key constraint "m2s_m3s_m2_id_fkey" on table "m2s_m3s"

table: m2s_m3s
constraint: m2s_m3s_m2_id_fkey
```

What am I missing? Is there a way to chain cascade deletions in Phoenix? Thanks!

Comment: It's a bit off topic, but cascading deletes can bring some confusion at some point, especially if your application is not trivial, just like active record callbacks and stuff like that, I'd suggest that you do this kinda stuff manually and explicitly but that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property you are looking for is called transitivity in general (M1 x M2 and M2 x M3, therefore M1 x M3). If you have the possibility to change the database schema (e.g. with your migration files) then you should consider to let the database take care of that. In the migration where you have `references(:m1s)` you could add `on_delete: :delete_all` resulting in `references(:m1s, on_delete: :delete_all)`. The same holds for the other tables.

See also https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html *:nilify_all and :delete_all will not cascade to child records unless set via database migrations.*